# How can I disable/enable a button in a bootbox dialog box

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

How can disable/enable the Save button?

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: [
    '<div class="title"'>,
    <h4>Title</h4>',
    </div>'].join(''),
    buttons: {
      label: 'Save',
      callback: function(){ // function code here  .....
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
$('.btn-save').prop("disabled", true);
```

where btn-save is the className of the button.

Comment: But how do you assign class to bootbox button? or where?

Answer (score 0):

For those using AngularJS, here how you can disable/enable a button whenever a value is present in a text input with ng-model="name":

```
var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    title: title,
    message: '<input type="text" ng-model="name" />',
    buttons: {
        apply: {
            label: 'Apply',
            className: 'btn btn-primary apply-btn',
            callback: function() {
                // whatever
            }
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'Cancel',
            className: 'btn btn-default',
        }
    }
});

dialog.bind('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $applyBtn = $(this).find('.apply-btn');
    $applyBtn.attr('ng-disabled', '!name');
    $compile($applyBtn)($s);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using web debugger (stopped on callback function) I found a solution based on user2884789's aswer:

```
$(this).find('button');
```

The save className button will appear in the list; ex: 'button.btn.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary'

So I disabled save button in callback function:

```
$(this).find('button.btn.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary').prop('disabled', true);
```

This worked for me.